# How to get total followers count of Twitter and Facebook using jQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook, twitter

Today I visited this blog, [Blogger Ever](http://bloggerever.com) and I saw a social counter. I do not want all of them just Twitter and Facebook follower count and their total. I know using Facebook Graph API I can extract likes like done in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nLNj/). Just want to get twitter followers count using jQuery, anyone can help?

```
var url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/google';
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    $('body').append(data.likes);
});
```

Comment: I get your requirements, but I'd question if it's necessary. Every time a user hits a page on your site, it's going to have to make 2 separate ajax request to get a number that I would doubt would change much (if at all) throughout the duration of their visit. Would it not be better to do this once (server side) and display it for the duration of their visit. Or caching the result for x amount of time and serving that number to all users?

Comment: Well dan, you are quite near but those who are using services like Blogger cannot do server stuff, so for them client-side is the option left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for twitter and total of their both. First go to [Twitter Counter](http://twittercounter.com/) it is the tool that gives stats of your twitter account and it also have an API. register your API Key from [this page](http://twittercounter.com/pages/api). After getting API key, you need to know your twitter id for that go to [this site](http://tweeterid.com/). After getting twitter id, just replace your twitter id and api key just replace in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nLNj/1/) and click run you will get your social counter.
**jQUERY**

```
  var apikey='REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_API';
     var twitterid='YOUR_TWITTER_ID';
$.when(

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "http://api.twittercounter.com/?twitter_id="+twitterid+"&apikey="+apikey+"&output=JSONP&callback=getcount",
        success: function (data) {
            var twitterfollowcount = data.followers_current;
            $(".twitter").html(twitterfollowcount);
        }
    }),$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://graph.facebook.com/bloggerever",
        success: function (data) {
            var facebookfollowcount = data.likes;
            $(".facebook").html(facebookfollowcount);
        }
    })  
    ).done(function (twitter,facebook) {
        var total =twitter[0].followers_current+facebook[0].likes;

        $('.total').append(total);
    });
```

**Note**
Twitter api used in the code above was not official by Twitter, now they have removed it, therefore twitter wont work.

Comment: thx but not worked today ! 
`message "An access token is required to request this resource."`

Comment: The solution is indeed outdated.